# Puppet can't find bundler command

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet with Vagrant but have a few issues around using rbenv to setup the Ruby installs.

Ruby is installing fine (I'm using the plugin: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/jdowning/rbenv to install ruby + gems as so:

```
rbenv::plugin { 'sstephenson/ruby-build': } ->
rbenv::build { '1.9.3-p392': global => true } ->
rbenv::gem { 'bundler': ruby_version => '1.9.3-p392' } ->
```

However after running this, Puppet cannot find the bundler command under rbenvs shim folder. I can see rbenv rehash events and examining the manifest of the plugin shows that it should rehash the binaries after running and gem installs etc.

If I ssh to the machine, a "which bundler" finds the path to the binary. Likewise, re-running the puppet script works correctly and installs everything fine.

At the moment I'm using the following command:

```
exec { "bundle install":
    user => $app_user,
    group => $app_group,
    command => "bundle install",
    path => [ '/bin/', '/sbin/', '/usr/bin/', '/usr/sbin/', "/home/${app_user}/.rbenv/bin/", "/home/${app_user}/.rbenv/shims/" ],
    cwd => $app_root,
} ->
```

The path is overkill I know.

Any ideas on what I could try next? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Don't know much about rbenv. The default shell is probably sh in non interactive mode. Does rbenv play with bashrc or bash_profile ? Needs to source a rbenv specific script ? try your command in a `/bin/bash -l ...`

Comment: @Samuel Did you ever find a solution? I am facing the exact same problem, and your question is one of the top search results.

Comment: Hey Frank, just saw your reply. I must have fixed it somehow but I'm not sure what I did. I vaguely remember some naming issues with the puppet autoload that required me to rename some of the folders that were checked out.

If it helps, here's my working Vagrant/Puppet config for getting Ruby setup.

https://gist.github.com/Rodeoclash/9165217

Answer (score 0):

It's important to make sure that all the gem setup is complete before you try to exec bundler, e.g.

```
exec { "bundle install": require => Rbenv::Gem["..."], ... }
```

Otherwise, it's possible that the rehash resource gets evaluated after your exec.